# how to restrict dates in datetime field - Sugarcrm

Tags: datepicker, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to restrict users selecting between dates, but I didn't find a solution to it. I tried the following initiatives to do it.

```
this.$("input[name='date_c']").datepicker({ maxDate: 1 });
```

How can I utilize the

```
_setupDatePicker
```

Function to restrict the user, is there some configuration to it?

Comment: Have you tried using javascript for that date restriction using rest api.

Comment: No @RaviRanjan i coudnt able to find any document to configur datepicker. or restriction using API. Do u know something about them?

Comment: u where talking about the call to an API to restrict.? thats not going to be a solution. I am trying to disable the date selections.

Comment: I am trying to achive something like this http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/PPSh3/3/

Comment: Not using any random API,  rest is SugarCRM official API and if you trying using that with Ajax then you will be able to use that jquery code which links your comment.

Comment: which Sugar version you are using?

Comment: @Star sugar 7.8

Answer (score 1):

if you check task module then Sugar manage this in task module for date start and date end but not in your required way i.e. disable dates but it restrict user to select due date greater then date start. It uses following code:

```
addToValidateDateBefore('EditView', 'date_start', 'datetimecombo', false,'Start Date', 'date_due' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside include\javascript\calendar.js
Search for *calendar.cfg.setProperty("selected", sanitizedDate)* this line and below that line add folowing lines

```
if(inputField==<id of the field> ){
 calendar.cfg.setProperty("maxDate", <maximum Date>); 
 calendar.cfg.setProperty("minDate", <Minimum Date>); 
       }
```

replace appropriate dates inside *maximum date* and *minimum date*